# Signed Applets don't Load

Tags: java, security, applet, appletviewer

After change in security in new version of Java there is a popup showing information about unsigned content every time site is reloaded. So we decided to sign our applets (and all libraries used). But after signing, all applets ceased to load on site, it’s just blank grey space.  After deploying signed jars we got information saying **“Application Blocked by Security settings”**.  When I click **‘OK’** applet shows information **"Error. Click for details"**, when I click it there is no information in applet console.

What can be reason of this?

Comment: Check the Bug Database.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Would you mind to elaborate on your comment? What's the "Bug Database" you are referring to? If it's a site, can you post the link so that other readers could make use of it too?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp  I don't mind at all.  Thanks for asking. :)  The site is the top link for the words 'Bug Database' in Google.  Every Java programmer should become familiar with it (and by *that* I mean both Google *and* the Bug Database).  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to resolve in my case:

-create jar per applet

-create jnlp file per applet outside jar file

-still you need jnlp in jar file in JNLP-INF

-set properties in manifest

-then sign every lib and jar with cert